# Using two = signs in CASE statement?

Tags: sql-server, case-statement

I'm attempting to use a case statement, dependent on a variable, to determine part of my WHERE clause, but it doesn't like what I'm doing. Here's my query (modified for simplicity)

```
DECLARE @SalesType VARCHAR(10)

SET @SalesType = 'Bulk'

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN fwsf.Customer_Cardlock_Customer = 'True'
            THEN 'CFN'
        ELSE 'Bulk'
        END AS 'Prod Type'
FROM TABLE t
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN @SalesType = 'Bulk' then t.customer_type = 'False'
        WHEN @SalesType = 'CFN' then t.customer_type = 'True'
        End
```

Put another way, I want to state in the WHERE clause that when the @SalesType is a given value, to select the rows that have another value.

EDIT:For sake of others, I realized I had another scenario where I may need to select an 'All' option. Per Shawn below, he corrected my original proposed solution with the following that I verified works:

```
AND t.customer_type =
CASE @SalesType
    WHEN 'Bulk' then 'False'
    WHEN 'CFN'  then 'True'
    WHEN 'All'  then t.customer_type
END
        END
```

Comment: That would explain it. Didn't realize it had that limitation. Any suggestions on how I might achieve my goal, if not by a CASE?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Note that I don't quite understand the connection between `Customer_Cardlock_Customer` and `@SalesType` but I think it's probably not relevant to answering the question. As per you nested `case`, I don't see that that will work right. Basically it was always evaluate to "False when given "All".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your summary is very good and this is a common way to *translate* or *decode* values. Per your edit there's also a case where you want *all* results.

```
WHERE t.customer_type =
    CASE @SalesType
        WHEN 'Bulk' then 'False'
        WHEN 'CFN'  then 'True'
        WHEN 'All'  then t.customer_type
    END
```

I've modified the expression to use a different form of `case`. You might find this to be more readable and at least now you know it exists.

I'll also note that in your original logic, if the `case` falls through then the result will be null.

The "all rows" can be handled by just returning the `customer_type` value which is naturally always equal to itself, *except when null*. To handle null you'd need to do something a bit more complicated like `coalesce(t.customer_type, 'ALL!')` on both sides of the equality.

If optimization is a concern you might be better off with regular `and`/`or` logic.

```
(
    @SalesType = 'Bulk' AND t.customer_type = 'False' OR
    @SalesType = 'CFN'  AND t.customer_type = 'True'  OR
    @SalesType = 'All'
)
```

Comment: Great catch. As I started putting this together, I realized I need to account for an 'All', which is both of these values...

Answer (score 5):

You can write your `WHERE` clause a bit more simpler:

```
where 
  (@SalesType = 'Bulk' and t.customer_type = 'False')
   OR
  (@SalesType = 'CFN' and t.customer_type = 'True')
   OR 
   @SalesType = 'All'
```

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` *expressions* can only return a value not a condition. So just move the column to compare outside the case expression, and then use the case expression to generate the value to compare.

```
DECLARE @SalesType VARCHAR(10);

SET @SalesType = 'Bulk';

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN fwsf.Customer_Cardlock_Customer = 'True' THEN 'CFN'
    ELSE 'Bulk'
    END AS 'Prod Type'
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.customer_type = CASE 
    WHEN @SalesType = 'Bulk' THEN 'False'
    WHEN @SalesType = 'CFN' THEN 'True'
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause then you can do something like:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE 
           WHEN @SalesType = 'Bulk' AND t.customer_type = 'False' THEN 1
           WHEN @SalesType = 'CFN' AND t.customer_type = 'True'THEN 1
           ELSE 0
          END
```